# How to use foreign key to get three table data

Tags: mysql, sql

#### item_master

```
(I_code(pk),I_name,I_unite,I_buy_price,I_stock_price,C_id,I_low_stock_value,I_current_stock,I_Active)
```

#### Supplier_master

```
(S_id(pk),S_name,S_Active)
```

#### Order_master

```
(O_id(PK),I_code(FK),S_id(FK),O_place_date,O_order_quantity,O_Receive_quantity)
```

Need Select query for get

```
I_code,S_name,I_name,I_stock_price,I_current_stock,O_order_quantity,O_Receive_quantity
```

using `O_id`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) What have you tried? What should the results look like? Are you wanting to exclude non-matching rows or receive `NULL` in their place?

Answer (score 1):

SELECT 
 I.* - - or your preferred fields
, S.* - - or your preferred fields
,I.* - - or your preferred fields
FROM 
   ORDER_MASTER O
   LEFT JOIN SUPPLIER_MASTER S ON O.S_id=S.S_id
   LEFT JOIN ITEM_MASTER I ON O.I_CODE=I.I_code

WHERE O.O_id=1

Sorry for the formatting, answering from phone. Please mark as Answer if it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT I.I_code, 
       S.S_name,
       I.I_name,
       I.I_stock_price,
       I.I_current_stock,
       O.O_order_quantity,
       O.O_Receive_quantity
FROM Order_master AS O
JOIN Supplier_master as S ON S.S_id = O.S_id
JOIN item_master AS I ON I.I_code = O.I_code
WHERE O.O_id = ?
```